How to deal with geometry nodes attributes
How to get maximum attribute value for each vertex, but the max value should be max among faces that connected with that vertex?
I have "face_count" attribute on faces. Now a need that every vertex have that attribute too, but the value should be the max value among faces that include corresponding vertex. How can I achieve that?


Face attribute copies to a face corner unchanged, so all you have to do is to find the face corner with the maximum value, which you can do by sorting them by that attribute and taking the last (-1):

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

@SergeiKrumas yea docs are incomplete but even when negative indices are not supported you can just multiply the weight by -1 and take the first element

@SergeiKrumas https://i.imgur.com/hPIguqO.png

I've done it on my own. Geonodes is a really strange thing.

EDIT: Later I improved the setup thanks to @MarkusvonBroady input and updating Blender from version 4.0 to 4.3. Blend file attached. The setup now supports arbitrary edges count for each vertex, earlier it was locked to 3.



You don't need the "store" node here; just connect "face neighbors" instead of "named attribute".  You can replace"sample index" with "evaluate at index" to reduce the number of links. You can remove "index" nodes,  as the implicit input for that socket is the same.  Your solution only works with triangles.

@MarkusvonBroady thanks for the input, indeed it is useful! Yes, my solution only works with triangles, but how can I achieve the the same result with arbitrary count of faces connected to vertex? Do you know the solution? Not sure that geonodes allow me achieve that right now. I'm using Blender 4.3.

Sorry, I misunderstood the setup, both solutions have the problem of assuming 3 neighbors, but it's not an assumption of triangles, rather that no vertex has more than 3 neighboring faces. It will fail in a typical quad topology, where most vertices have 4 face neighbors and especially in UV sphere poles.

@MarkusvonBroady Yes, but the second solution is much smarter, we can just change the value of "iterations" socket to 4 and it will support 4 edges too, so don't need to duplicate the nodes as in the first solution. Or we just precalculate the maximum edges count for all verticies before Repeat zone and feed it to the "iterations" socket.

@MarkusvonBroady Yes, in UV sphere not all vertices have the same amont of adjacent faces as poles do, and repeat zone will overiterate on some vertices, BUT it still works due to wrap-around nature of "Sort Index" socket AND my task is completed albeit in a strange manner. I do much better work for this task in Houdini, but in Blender I must follow that concept rules. This is the situation when you can write code for the task faster then trying to build something out of geonodes concepts.
